# TYPO3 menu: exclude branch/folder from menu when using entryLevel

Tags: menu, typo3

My menu looks like the following

```
Home
--Category 1
----Subpage
----Subpage
--Category 2
----Subpage
----Subpage
--Folder
----Subpage
----Subpage
```

My TS looks like the following

```
lib.mainmenu_level2 = HMENU
lib.mainmenu_level2 {
  entryLevel = 1

  # Level 2
  1 = TMENU
  1.wrap = <ul class="nav-level-2 clearfix">|</ul>
  1 {
    # no state 
    NO {
      wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first">|</li> |*| <li>|</li> |*| <li class="last">|</li>
      ATagTitle.field = title
      stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    }
 ...
```

Now I want that I get all subpages from the entryLevel 1. This works so far until I'm on a subpage of `Folder`. Here I get the subpages, but this subpages should not be presented to the user. Can I exclude all subpages from `Folder` somehow? I cannot hide them in the menu because of the mc_googlesitemap extensions (otherwise it would not be present in the XML sitemap). Or is the only way pulling the subpages out from `Folder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HMENU` has the configuration value `excludeUidList`.

```typoscript
lib.mainmenu_level2 = HMENU
lib.mainmenu_level2 {
    entryLevel = 1
    excludeUidList = 46,34,78
    ...
```

Adding the UID of the Folder should work.
http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/HMENU